# ios existing ca email address required

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain

When using keychain and certificate assistant to request a certificate from an existing CA, all the instructions say that I should click the "save to disk" option and that the "CA Email Address" should not be required.

The panel I see does not offer an option for "save to disk" and when I attempt to click continue without a CA Email Address it fails with the message that the CA email address is required.

How can I find what the CA Email address should be?

Do I have an obsolete version of the certificate assistant? When I check for updates it says that no updates are available. (Running OS X V 10.4.11 on a 1.42 GHz PowerPC G4 with 1 Gb DDR SDRAM)

Answer (score 15):

**Solution:**

[image: Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority window]

- In the code signing request (CSR) window, there would be a field called **"Request is"**, choose the radio button corresponding to **"Save to disk"**.

**Reason why you faced the problem:**

- By default the the **"Request is"** field is chosen as  **"Emailed to the CA"**.

**Note:**

- To get to the CSR window, open  Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.

**Refer:**

- https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/create.action

Comment: Make sure you have selected "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" before selecting the "Certificate Assistant > Request ..." from the file menu. I had some other certificate selected from my list and the "Save to disk" method did not work. After selecting the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" it worked.